# List of unsuitable fonts

Tags: fonts, calligraphy, mathcal

It seems that the actual answer to this question is "It's up to you". However I often read in `tex.SE` some comments that oppose the usage of certain fonts, in somehow an absolute character. That suggests that some fonts are widely used, while some others, frown upon (depending on the situation, of course).

I don't mean some fonts are uglier than others, but there are presumably situations in which their use is inappropriate. I'd like to see suggestions of the community for:

- Unsuitable fonts for talks slides (`beamer`).
- Unsuitable fonts for papers.
- Unsuitable fonts for math calligraphy.
- Unsuitable ...(you might want to add some other situations)

Comment: Don't use bitmap-based fonts but outline fonts.

Comment: For teh lulz http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `Zapf chancery` for math. Instead use `mathcal`. And say no to comic sans in papers, talks etc.

Answer (score 5):

This is mostly, I admit, opinionated prejudice, but I dislike:

- Serif fonts in general for Beamer presentations
- Sans-serif fonts in general for body text